# Cloning a Firebase Project (including User Accounts)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm looking to clone an entire Firebase project to create a testing version of the database with the existing security rules and user accounts (and their passwords) in place. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [other similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640419/how-to-setup-a-duplicate-project-in-firebase), no, there is no easy way to do this.

Google pushes their Firestore product which seems to [allow this more easily](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data), over the free/low cost Firebase Realtime Database, so I wouldn't hold your breath on new functionality within the original Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: This answer is a bit confusing because Google's branding has changed (and was always confusing): Firebase is now an entire family of products, and Firestore is a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning firebase users refer to this document [Import users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users) or you can visit this question for a solution [duplicate firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22697499/8939573).