# How to setup a duplicate project in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I would like to create a duplicate project in firebase so that I dont have to go through the hassle of adding the firebase functions and notifications etc. If I could I would just delete all auth users so that its ready for the actual app but I am unable to do that.

So How can I set up a duplicate project but without all the authenticated test users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no simple way to duplicate a project.  The best you can do is use the [management API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest) and the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) and Firebase CLI to script the provisioning and setup of the products you use.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: Is this still the case?